# Unable to select options from IOS picker in Xamarin.UITest

Tags: ios, xamarin.uitest

I am using Xamarin.UITest to write automated tests for our mobile apps.  Selecting from a picker in IOS I can't see the options.  This used to work:

> public Query FrequencyOption(string value) => x => x.Marked(value);

but since IOS framework upgrade, I can no longer view elements in an IOS picker.  The options are not listed as you can see in this screenshot.  Hoping someone can help me with how to interact with these items in the spinner below

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I have reported this issue here: https://github.com/microsoft/appcenter/issues/2518#issuecomment-1446771807

it appears to be just an iOS 16 and higher issue that they should be fixing. Keep in mind it should still work on iOS 15 and lower as it did before.